# Query with join from MSSQL to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, table-alias

I have this query which runs on MsSQL:

```
select BL.ID from O_USERS_BATCH
as UB join O_BATCH_LOCK as BL on UB.INSTANCE_ID = BL.ID order by BL.ID
```

How do I convert it to work with Oracle data base type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only change is to drop the `as`:

```
select BL.ID
from O_USERS_BATCH ub join
     O_BATCH_LOCK BL
     on UB.INSTANCE_ID = BL.ID
order by BL.ID;
```

Oracle doesn't support `as` for table aliases.